# When to use pkg_check_modules as a fallback to find<package>?

Tags: cmake

I use `find<package>` to probe for packages (ZLIB, PNG, ...) and `pkg_check_modules` as a fallback if `FindPackage` fails to set up a superbuild with external dependencies:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)

## find_package(ZLIB) is a bit redundant; find_package(PNG) seems to probe for ZLIB
## in newer versions of FindPNG.cmake...
find_package(ZLIB)
find_package(PNG)

if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
    if (NOT ZLIB_FOUND)
        pkg_check_modules(ZLIB IMPORTED_TARGET zlib)
    endif (NOT ZLIB_FOUND)
    if (NOT PNG_FOUND)
        pkg_check_modules(PNG IMPORTED_TARGET libpng)
    endif (NOT PNG_FOUND)
endif ()

if (NOT ZLIB_FOUND)
    ## Set up external project dependency build
else ()
    ## Found it, incorporate into target's link stage
endif ()
```

The problem is when `MinGWw64` is installed and `CMake` uses the VS2019 compiler -- `pkg_check_modules` finds `MinGWw64`'s `zlib`, which can't be used due to the different library naming convention.

I've added `MSVC` to the condition, since this seems to only impact MSVC-based builds:

```
if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND AND NOT (MSVC))
    # ...
endif()
```

Since I'm aiming to be as cross-platform as possible (*nix, MSVC, MinGW), is there a better way to fall back to `pkg_check_modules` when `find<package>` doesn't succeed? Or should I avoid `pkg_check_modules` altogether?

Comment: Actually, almost any package has its own specific about searching that package. I would leave this specific to its `FindXXX.cmake` script (or, better, to its `XXXConfig.cmake` script). Also, some `FindXXX.cmake` scripts already use `pkg_config` in their work, so additional call to `pkg_check_modules` is just a waste of time.

Comment: I would expect a search mechanism in `FindXXX.cmake` script (if exists) is not worse than the one, provided by `pkg-config`. If the first fails but the latter succeed, then it is probably a matter of proper setting of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or some other environment or CMake variable. It could be simpler for you, as the developer, to require a user to set a single variable, than to support `pkg_check_modules` fallback in your project. (And cross-platform would make this support even harder).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid stupid: Let `find_package` do the work, as some `Find<package>.cmake` scripts (recipes) use `PkgConfig.cmake` internally as a fallback.